# Sql pattern in like condition

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

Simple issue :

I have fields (path) like :

```
1/2/43
1/2/43/45
1/2/43/45/46
```

I want to be able to get the path containing 43/XX

Meanings here the only valid one would be

```
1/2/43/45
```

This seems not to be working

```
... WHERE path LIKE '%43/[0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: `LIKE` cannot be used with regex.

Comment: Tag your question with the databsase you are using.

Comment: String functions are highly vendor specific. Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: @GordonLinoff MySql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only SQL Server supports using (a small subset of) regular expressions with `LIKE`. In MySQL, you would use `RLIKE`, or `REGEXP` (both are synonyms). Your condition would translate as:

```
WHERE path RLIKE '43/[0-9][0-9]'
```

This can be shortened with a quantifier:

```
WHERE path RLIKE '43/[0-9]{2}'
```

You might want to be a little more specific by ensuring that the character that precedes `43` is either a slash or the beginning of the string:

```
WHERE path RLIKE '(^|/)43/[0-9]{2}'
```

The same constraint can be applied to the right side of the string:

```
WHERE path RLIKE '(^|/)43/[0-9]{2}(/|$)'
```

Comment: WHERE path RLIKE '(^|/)43/[0-9]{2}$'

This was exactly what I was looking for thanks